# Hammer BSP file size inefficiency

Tags: steam

I haven't posted here before but I came across a problem, when I save a map in Hammer as `.bsp` it ends up being over 10x bigger than all of the source files put together. I found the source for one map `rp_downtown_v2.bsp`, which the map is 2mb but when I used the source and compiled it in hammer its 40MB? Why would this be? Any further help will aid thanks!

Comment: What is hammer?

Comment: @Phill.Zitt part of Source SDK. This belongs on Gamedev.SE

Comment: @kotekzot - Okay, that makes things so much clearer. Thanks for that. And agreed, this should be on Gamedev.SE

Comment: Please add the list of WAD files you have included in your VHE for the map. It might be that you're baking the WAD's in the BSP, and that there are too many of them.

Comment: So what's the actual problem?

Answer (score 1):

The BSP file format stores a lot of information in it. For one it takes your brushes from Hammer and performs CSG on them to create all the triangles that are to be rendered. It then calculates other complex information such as planes, edges, surfaces, visibility, etc. that is not part of the source file.

But the largest contributor to the file size would probably be the lightmaps, which are textures used to give the map shadows. Each face in the map will have a lightmap texture, so the more faces you have the more lightmaps you need. Being a texture, they take up a fair amount of space (compared to other binary data).

See this article for more information: [Source BSP File Format](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Source_BSP_File_Format).

Comment: Is there any way to obfuscate it? Like fully compile it? Or are you saying there's files inside the bsp that are useless and can be removed?